# C++14 compile time std::array with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, stdarray

I'd like to build a compile time lookup table using c++14 variadic templates.
At the moment I'm there:

```
static const unsigned kCount = 5;

template<unsigned Index>
constexpr auto getRow(void)
{
    return std::array<unsigned, 2> { Index, Index * Index };
}

template<unsigned... Indices>
constexpr auto generateTable(std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    return std::array<std::array<unsigned, 2>, sizeof...(Indices)>
    {
        // This is were I'm stuck. How to build a std::array using Indices as template parameter in getRow()?
    };
}

constexpr auto generate(void)
{
    return generateTable(std::make_index_sequence<kCount>{});
}
```

I want the table to be in a `std::array`. Each row consists of a `std::array` with 2 columns. I'm stuck in `generateTable()` where I need to somehow pass my Indices to `getRow()` as a template parameter.

Is this achievable using `std::integer_sequence` and template parameter pack expansion or do I need to implement the recursion on my own?

(`getRow()` is simplified - the value types are actually coming from templated types. `Index * Index` is just a placeholder. I need to know the way how to call `getRow()` using parameter pack expansion.)

Comment: What is `Index` ? Row number ?

Comment: Yes, Index is the row number. Currently running from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're almost there.  Just rely on parameter-pack expansion:

```
return std::array<std::array<unsigned, 2>, sizeof...(Indices)>
{
   getRow<Indices>()...
};
```

where the `getRow<Indices>()...` line will expand to:

```
getRow<0>(), getRow<1>(), ..... , getRow<sizeof...(Indices)-1>()
```

Answer (score 4):

+1 for the solution of KyleKnoepfel but I have problems compiling your code in my amd64 linux because "error: no matching function for call to 'generateTable'" and "candidate template ignored: substitution failure : deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the its corresponding template parameter ('unsigned long' vs 'unsigned int')"

The problem is that `std::make_index_sequence<kCount>{}` generate a sequence of `std::size_t`. If `std::size_t` is defined as `unsigned int`, all goes well; if (like in my platform) `std::size_t` is defined as `unsigned long`, the following declaration didn't work

```
template<unsigned... Indices>
constexpr auto generateTable(std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
```

Suggestion: use ever `std::size_t` instead `unsigned`; particularly

```
template<std::size_t ... Indices>
constexpr auto generateTable(std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
```

En passant, initialize a `std::array` with `{ val1, val2 }` (only one level of braces) it's perfectly legal in C++14 but (IMHO) I think it's better to use the old (C++11) syntax with a double level of braces (`{ { val1, val2 } }`); this for backwards compatibility (as pointed by Wum) and to avoid annoying warnings with some compilers (like clang++ 3.5). So I suggest to use a second level of braces in array declaration/initialization, so

```
return std::array<unsigned, 2> { { Index, Index * Index } };
```

and

```
return std::array<std::array<unsigned, 2>, sizeof...(Indices)>
 { { getRow<Indices>() ... } };
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks for your hint concerning `std::size_t`. I will keep this in mind. Could  you please explain the advantages of the 2nd level of curly braces?

Comment: Upvote on the `std::size_t` recommendation, but why recommend double braces?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array tells that double braces are needed for C++11 to keep the aggregate initialization in `std::array` working. So this seems to be a matter of backwards compatibiliy.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode (and Wum) - Sorry: my fault; I ever forget that C++14 relaxed the syntax. But, as said by Wum, for backward compatibility reason (and to avoid annoying warning with some compilers, like clang 3.5) I think it's better to use the old syntax. Modified the answer to (try to) make clear this point.